# Splitting rows of a file in half (C)

Tags: c, io

Using just I/O system calls, I should write I program in C that takes a file as input and prints in output its contents splitting each line in half. More specifically, if a line is n characters long, the program must print the first n/2 characters of a line, followed by a '\n' print, followed by its second n/2 characters. I wrote down a possible solution but it doesn't working very well, splitting the correct lines for a half of the file content and ignoring the rest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LEN 5000

void half_rows (char* f);
void freebuf (char arr[], int n);

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

    if (argc != 2)
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage %s: <file>\n", argv[0]), exit(1);

    char* file = argv[1];
    half_rows (file);

    return 0;

}

void half_rows (char* f){

    char c;
    char buf[LEN];
    int fd, nread, n, rest, up;
    if (( fd = open (f, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        perror("opening error"), exit(1);
    int cur = lseek (fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    int finalpos = lseek (fd, 0, SEEK_END);
//  lseek (fd, cur, SEEK_SET);

    do{
        lseek (fd, cur, SEEK_SET);
        if ((nread = read (fd, &c, sizeof(c))) < 0)
            perror("reading error"), exit(1);
        buf[cur] = c;
        if ( buf[cur] == '\n' || buf[cur] == '\0'){
            rest = cur % 2;
            if (rest == 0)
                n = cur / 2;
            else{
                up = cur + 2 - rest;
                n = up / 2;
            }

            buf[n] = '\n';
            buf[n+1] = '\0';

        }
        ++cur;
    }while (cur < finalpos);

    write (STDOUT_FILENO, buf, finalpos);


}
```

Comment: I don't undertand your algorithm at all. `cur` is the current position in the file, not the position in the line. Why are you dividing it in half?

Comment: Create two buffers, one for the first half, another for the second half. Read each line with `fgets()`, and split it in half. Append the first half to the first buffer, the second half to the second buffer.

Comment: @Barmar Could you please write down an example? Thank you

Comment: @Barmar with examples lmao I'd learn the approach at least, never mind I'll do it by my own

Comment: I don't know how to write an example that isn't the whole program.

Comment: Do you need all the first 1/2 lines written out and then all the second 1/2 lines? Or, do you just need to split each line writing first 1/2, second 1/2, first 1/2, second 1/2, etc....?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, I need the first half of a line followed by a new line followed by its second half, and so on.

Comment: Ok, that's much easier. Read each line with `fgets()`, then use `strlen()` to find the length. Then either save the mid-character (and the next) and replace with `'\n', '\0'`, to add a newline and nul-termate at 1/2 the line, output line, restore both original characters and output `line + len/2`. Or you can use a 2nd array and `memcpy()` the first 1/2 line to that array and add `'\n', '\0'` at the end and output that, then the rest of the line.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks a lot! You've made your point. I got it now! thank you

Comment: Good deal, if you get stuck, post what you've got and we will help further. Once you read the whole line, if you use a 2nd array to hold the first 1/2, you can do, e.g. `memcpy (first, line, len/2); first[len/2] = '\n'; first[len/2+1] = 0;` and output `first`, then output `line + len/2`. See what you can do.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Alright, I appreciate that!

Comment: What is all this talk of "2 buffers"?  You are making the problem far more complicated than it is.  All you need to do is inject newlines in the right place.   One approach would be to simply read through the file twice.  On the first pass, find out where the newlines are.  On the second pass,output each character and insert an additional newline half way between each.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Either replace `len/2` and `len/2 + 1` with `"\n\0"` or just copy first 1/2 to another array. I don't see either one or the other being more complicated (you would have to save and restore the 2 chars if you inject). You can't make 2-passes and print 1st 1/2, 2nd 1/2 for each line one after the other.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sure you can.  Sample code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can let `printf` do it all for you, without a copy or injection or you can copy or inject, or do it char-by-char as @WilliamPursell shows (all are fine), e.g.

**With Printf**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char line[MAXC];    /* buffer to hold entire line */

    while (fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) {     /* read/validate line */
        int len = strlen(line);             /* get length of line */

        if (len == 1) {                     /* if line only 1-char */
            putchar (line[0]);              /* can't split 1 - output char */
            continue;                       /* get next line */
        }

        /* output first 1/2 and second 1/2 */
        printf ("%.*s\n%s", len/2, line, line + len/2);
    }
}
```

**Using a 2<sup>nd</sup> Buffer**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char line[MAXC];    /* buffer to hold entire line */

    while (fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) {     /* read/validate line */
        size_t len = strlen(line);          /* get length of line */
        char first[MAXC/2 + 1];             /* buffer to hold 1st 1/2 */

        if (len == 1) {                     /* if line only 1-char */
            putchar (line[0]);              /* can't split 1 - output char */
            continue;                       /* get next line */
        }

        memcpy (first, line, len/2);        /* copy 1st 1/2 to first */
        first[len/2] = '\n';                /* add newline (or just use puts) */
        first[len/2+1] = 0;                 /* nul-termiante */

        fputs (first, stdout);              /* output 1st 1/2 */
        fputs (line + len/2, stdout);       /* output rest */
    }
}
```

Both will give equivalent output, e.g.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/tosplit.txt
1234
56789
123

bc
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitline < dat/tosplit.txt
12
34
567
89
12
3

b
c
```

There is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat* in C. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This has the huge advantage of being able to work on a stream.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try storing lines.  Just read the file twice, and inject newlines as needed.  eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *a, *b;
        int c;
        a = xfopen( argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "input", "r");
        b = xfopen( argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "input", "r");

        do {
                int alen = 0;
                int blen = 0;
                while( ( c = fgetc(a)) != '\n' && c != EOF ) {
                        alen += 1;
                }
                while( ( c = fgetc(b)) != '\n' && c != EOF ) {
                        if( blen++ ==alen / 2) {
                                putchar('\n');
                        }
                        putchar(c);
                }
                if( c != EOF)
                        putchar('\n');
        } while( c != EOF );

        return 0;
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
        FILE *fp = fopen(path, mode);
        if( fp == NULL ) {
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return fp;
}
```

Comment: Point well taken, a char-by-char approach avoids the copy or injection.